# Using one authentication with several web applications inside ear

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, jax-rs

I have a JSF-based web application which uses form-authentication. The security-domain is set up in `jboss` config. I also have a `JAX-RS` application which contains REST-API, and I want some of its methods to be accessed only by users whis are authenticated in first App. 

I took a look on the jasig `CAS` but it seems a little to heavy for my purpose and I suppose there is a simpler solution and maybe you guys would help me to find it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need can be solved with [Oauth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Your backend (REST-API) will require authenticated access to your API operations. In turn, your front-end (JSF-based web app) will need to issue authenticated requests when communicating with the backend. This is achieved by sending `access tokens`.

Although this could seem complex, it will be very useful for you to take a look at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com). We have quite a straightforward solution for this. Please take a look at [Using Stormpath for API Authentication](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/).

As a summary, your solution will look like this:

1. You will use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs.
2. In your front, when the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials securely to your backend-end thorough its REST API.

   2.1. By the way, Stormpath greatly enhances all the possibilities here. Instead of having your own login page, you can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/), or you can also delegate it to our [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html). Stormpath also supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login.
3. Your backend will then try to authenticate the user against the Stormpath Backend and will return an `access token` as a result:

   ```
   /** This code will throw an Exception if the authentication fails */
   public void postOAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       //Getting the authentication result
       AccessTokenResult result = (AccessTokenResult) application.authenticateApiRequest(request);

       //Here you can get all the user data stored in Stormpath
       Account account = accessTokenResult.getAccount();

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
       response.setContentType("application/json");

       //Output the json of the Access Token
       response.getWriter().print(token.toJson());
       response.getWriter().flush();
   }
   ```
4. Then, for every authenticated request, your backend will do:

   ```
   public void getEquipment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       OauthAuthenticationResult result = (OauthAuthenticationResult) application.authenticateOauthRequest(request).execute();

       System.out.println(result.getApiKey());
       System.out.println(result.getAccount());

       //Return what you need to return in the response
       handleEquipmentRequest(response);
   }
   ```

Please take a look [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens) for more information

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.